# Use std::find on QVector<std::unique_ptr<Type>>

Tags: c++, qt

#### The code

Below is a downsized implementation of a class I'm having trouble with:

```
class Dummy{
public:
    Dummy();
    ~Dummy();
    void addItem(std::unique_ptr<Type>&& item);
private:
    QVector<std::unique_ptr<Type>> collection;
}
```

The `Type`, in the code snippet above, is another class which supports move semantics.
Here's the implementation of the `addItem` member:

```
void Dummy::addItem(std::unique_ptr<Type>&& item){
    if((std::find(collection.begin(), collection.end(), item) == colection.end()){
        collection.push_back(std::move(item));
    }
}
```

I use the class `Dummy` as follows:

```
Dummy myDummy;
std::unique_ptr<Type> item(new Type());
myDummy.addItem(sdt::move(item));
```

#### The problem

The compiler reports the following:

```
required from 'QVector<T>::iterator QVector<T>::begin()'
required from here
use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp,_Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp,_Dp>&)'
```

Does this mean that I cannot iterate with the provided iterators over a `QVector<std::unique_ptr<Type>>` and hence cannot use `std::find` provided by the algorithms header?
I could use a range-base for `for(auto const& other : collection)` and implement the equality operator for `Type` in order to get the behaviour from `std::find`.
I'm failing to grasp where the example goes wrong.

Comment: You are **never** going to find a `unique_ptr` equal to `item` in `collection`, because they are all *unique*. You should be looking for a `unique_ptr` which owns a `Type` equal to one owned by the contents of `collection`, try `std::find_if` with a suitable *UnaryPredicate*

Comment: The problem is caused by attempt to perform a copy of a unique pointer element. You have to avoid it.

Comment: @vahancho that's correct, but where precisely? When `collection.begin()` is called, the damage is already done. The cause of the error, seems to happen before that call.

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, it does make sense to use `std::find_if` instead of `std::find`. But it does not solve the compiler issue.

Comment: `QVector<T>::iterator` is [documented to be](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#iterator-typedefx) an alias for `T *`, so I think something fishy is going on if `collection.begin()` *on it's own* is failing to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `QVector` copies (copy constructs) its elements when you:

- Add them with `push_back()` function.
- Get non-constant iterator to the container's end.

To avoid the second one you have to use rather const iterators, i.e. `QVector::constBegin()` and `QVector::constEnd()`, i.e.

```
if (std::find(collection.constBegin(), collection.constEnd(), item) == collection.constEnd()) {...}
```

To avoid copying on addition... hm, I advice using rather `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You're right. The issue shifted from `collection.begin()` to `collection.push_back(std::move(item))` when I altered the iterators to `constBegin()` and `constEnd()` respectively.
The issue was resolved by using `std::vector` instead of `QVector`.

Comment: I don't think you can solve copying issue with `QVector` due to its shared data paradigm, when it copies data on write, when you call `push_back()`.